# Display thumbnails of videos stored on a file server

Tags: 2013, video, thumbnail, file-server

A department has 50GB of video files, which will gradually increase to 150GB - this makes me hesitate moving all of this in to a Video Library in Sharepoint.

A Media web part gives no option to connect to a file server location.

I know a Page Viewer web part can be used to display a Page/Folder/File on a Sharepoint page, so I can get the names of the mp4s to appear, but displaying video thumbnails does not seem possible:

[image: Screen shot of a Page Viewer page in Sharepoint - configured to display a network drive]

However, what I'd really like is a thumbnail of the videos to show instead.  Is this possible?